# best way to compare file contents containing non ascii chars using unix shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I have the following file:

```
~$ od file.txt 
0000000 000012
0000001
```

And I would like to be able in a bash script to make sure that a file has these contents.
I would like to avoid perl and would like to use standard unix tools including od/sed/awk/tr etc.

Can you recommend a nice and clean way of doing it?

Answer (score 5):

Use `cmp -s` to compare two files byte by byte, outputting nothing, only setting the exit status.

Answer (score 3):

If you know them to be similar,

```
diff <(xxd file1.txt) <(xxd file2.txt)
```

is a poor man's hexedit compare.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with small files and want to be sure that file content equals to some predefined non-textual value and also you don't want to compare files with some template, you can use something like this:

```
if [ "`hexdump -e '"%02x"' foo`" = 'deadd00d' ]; then
  # Right file content.
else
  # File differs.
fi
```

Of course, you might want to limit the output of the `hexdump` to avoid problems with too big input files.